# Lower bound for the random matrix inequality

Tags: probability, inequality, banach-spaces, random, random-matrices

For a matrix $A$ and sequence of its singular values $s(A)=(s_1(a), \ldots, s_n(A))$ the Shatten norm is defined as

$$
\|A\|_{S_p}=\|s(A)\|_p, \quad 1\leq p<\infty.
$$
Denote by $\bar r=(r_1, \ldots, r_N)$ random variables such that $Proba(r_i)=1=Proba(r_j)=-1=1/2$ and with condition that $r_1+\ldots r_N=B$.

Find lower bound of
$$
E\|\sum_{i=1}^Nr_iA_i\|^p_{S_p}\geq ?
$$

Note: I would expect that  $E\|\sum_{i=1}^Nr_iA_i\|^p_{S_p}\geq C(p, B) min \{
\|(\sum_{i=1}^NA^*_iA_i)^{1/2}\|^p_{S_p}, \|\sum_{i=1}^NA_iA^*_i)^{1/2}\|^p_{S_p}\}$, but not sure how to work with condition on random variables.